# Where to put my sqlalchemy join queries in mvc pattern?

Tags: python-3.x, model-view-controller, flask-sqlalchemy

I hope you are doing well

I have two models, `UserModel` and `PostModel` in separate files, inside a `Model` folder. The SQLAlchemy queries are within those models and my controllers calls those methods:

**UserModel**

```
class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.String(36), primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique = True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))

    def __init__(self, id: str = None, username: str = None, password: str = None) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def serialize(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'username': self.username,
            'password': self.password
        }

    @classmethod
    def get_users(cls):
        return cls.query.all()

    @classmethod
    def get_user(cls, id):
        return cls.query.filter_by(id = id).one()
```

**PostModel**

```
class PostModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'

    id = db.Column(db.String(36), primary_key=True)
    uid = db.Column(db.String(36), db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String())
    body = db.Column(db.String())

    def __init__(self, id: str = None, uid: str = None, title: str = None, body: str = None) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.uid = uid
        self.title = title
        self.body = body

    def serialize(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'uid': self.uid,
            'title': self.title,
            'body': self.body
        }

    @classmethod
    def get_posts(cls):
        return cls.query.all()

    @classmethod
    def get_post_by_id(cls, id: str):
        return cls.query.filter_by(id = id).one()

    @classmethod
    def get_post_by_uid(cls, uid: str):
        return cls.query.filter_by(uid = uid).all()
```

Suppose I want to join `post` with `user` by `uid`, then if this is my PostModel, I would likely do something like:
`cls.query.join(UserModel, UserModel.id == PostModel.uid).all()`
But to achieve that I would need to import my UserModel into my PostModel, which is bad because they should be independant from each other.

I thought of having a separate file named "queries.py" or something like that and put all my queries there, and then have the controllers import from this file, but I'm not sure if that's good or bad practice. If it's good, it should be inside my `Models` folder?

Is there another work around?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, totally normal to have all sql models in seperate file, mines usually `sqlmodels.py` and thats where they all live.

Comment: It is usual to use a r[elationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many) instead of explicit queries for a user's posts. Note that `Post` already has a dependency on `User` via the foreign key, so I wouldn't get too bothered about trying to keep them "independent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah thats totally fine to have all models in seperate file.

See some boiler plate examples below

https://github.com/realpython/flask-boilerplate

https://github.com/wilson-boca/flask-boilerplate-blueprint/tree/master/flaskapp

https://github.com/abstractkitchen/flask-backbone